# What am I doing wrong? Messages won't delete

Tags: php, sql, sql-delete

Ive been working on my delete.php file to delete selected messages for literally hours on end without any headway. How would I delete messages with the codes I have set up?

Heres the code to how my delete.php is set up right now

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Location:inbox.php");

    $user = $_SESSION['username'];

    include 'connect.php';


   foreach($_POST['messages'] as $num => $messages_id)

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM messages WHERE messages_id='$messages_id' AND to_user='$user'");

    ?>
```

Here's the code to my entire inbox.php

```
<?php
require "connect.php";

echo "<hr><br><div id='mail'>";

// get the messages from the table.
$get_messages = mysql_query("SELECT messages_id FROM messages WHERE 

to_user='$userfinal' ORDER BY messages_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$get_messages2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='$userfinal' 

ORDER BY messages_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$num_messages = mysql_num_rows($get_messages);
// display each message title, with a link to their content
echo '<ul>';
for($count = 1; $count <= $num_messages; $count++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($get_messages2);
    $fromuser = $row['from_user'];
    $messageid = $row['messages_id'];
    $messagetitle = $row['message_title'];
    $messageread = $row['message_read'];
    $messagedate = $row['message_date'];



    echo " <form name='send' method='post' action='delete.php'><input type='checkbox' name='delete' value='$messageid'></td><font face='helvetica'><font size='3'>$fromuser</font></font> &nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;  <div align='right'><a href='read_message.php?messages_id=$messageid'>$messagetitle</a></div>
<center><hr></center>


";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete Selected">
</table>
</div>
```

Please help out before my head explodes

Comment: Could you show us the entire html doc (or the form elements in order?).  Also, add `or die(mysql_error());` to the end of the `mysql_query()` so it should look like `mysql_query("DELETE FROM messages WHERE messages_id='$messages_id' AND to_user='$user'") or die (mysql_error());`  That will tell us if it is an error with the query.  Though don't leave it, not a good thing to have floating around on a live site.

Comment: a) Run mysql_real_escape_string on variables used in the query. b) Print your query to see what delete stament actually looks like on submit.

Comment: maybe some relating coulmens are wrong or somthing?

Comment: @mazzzzz thanks for the or die, cant believe i forgot that. but it still wont do anything. the message gets highlighted, i click on delete, the page refreshes, but the message is still there

Comment: Why on earth are you echoping a bunch of forms with the same name in the loop? Where are you closing any of those duplicate forms? And font tags?! Within another font tags?! You really need to brush up on some html.

Comment: What does the `or die(mysql_error())` say?

Comment: @imoda Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in delete.php on line 8

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at delete.php on line 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `header("Location:inbox.php");` in the second line of your code, so the rest of it never gets executed.

Just move it to the end of the script, after you have deleted the messages you wanted to delete.

Comment: hm, I actually had to look that up, but header doesn't stop the execution of code, only adds a header to be sent to the browser

Comment: thanks. before this, i couldnt see an error. Now when I try and delete, this comes up Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in delete.php on line 10

Comment: @mazzzzz `header('Location:...')` redirects to another page, effectively stopping execution of the current script, although you normally want to finish it off with `die()` just in case.

Comment: @Mohamed Yusuf Well, start with a `var_dump($_POST);` then and remove the `header` until everything is working.

Comment: @jeroen an example I can give is type `header('Location: google.com');unlink(__FILE__);`  If you notice, the file will be deleted after you are redirected.  Could you clarify when the page would stop?

Comment: sending location header does NOT stop the execution of the script. but since it redirects the browser you won't see the problems (warnings) your script might have. It's better to write a special location function which redirect instantly in production environment and waits for a couple of seconds / asks the user to click in dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
name='delete[]' value='<?php echo $messageid?>'

$_POST['delete']
```

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the problem is that you are adding a form tag for each checkbox (and not closing that form tag).  Instead put all the checkboxes in the same form, and name them `delete[]` the brackets at the end put each checkbox in an array inside the $_POST array.  So you can loop through them.

Here is an edited version (Note: not tested)

```
<?php
require "connect.php";

echo "<hr><br><div id='mail'>";

// get the messages from the table.
$get_messages = mysql_query("SELECT messages_id FROM messages WHERE 

to_user='$userfinal' ORDER BY messages_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$get_messages2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='$userfinal' 

ORDER BY messages_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$num_messages = mysql_num_rows($get_messages);
// display each message title, with a link to their content

echo "<form name='send' method='post' action='delete.php'>";

echo '<ul>';
for($count = 1; $count <= $num_messages; $count++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($get_messages2);
    $fromuser = $row['from_user'];
    $messageid = $row['messages_id'];
    $messagetitle = $row['message_title'];
    $messageread = $row['message_read'];
    $messagedate = $row['message_date'];

    echo "
    <input type='checkbox' name='messages[]' value='$messageid'></td>
    <font face='helvetica' size='3'>$fromuser</font>&nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;
    <div align='right'>
        <a href='read_message.php?messages_id=$messageid'>$messagetitle</a>
    </div>
    <center><hr></center>
    \n\n\n";
}

echo '</form>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete Selected">
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Since I deleted the header location, it just stays on an empty page. how would I set up delete.php?

Comment: it shows thisWarning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in delete.php on line 8

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at delete.php on line 14

Comment: type `print_r($_POST)` and post it up